# Angular ui-router 1.0.0rc transition superseded on a redirect

Tags: angularjs, redirect, angular-ui-router

Angular 1.6.1 and ui-router 1.0.0rc;

I'm running into an issue with ui-router while redirecting from one state to another.

A `TransitionRejection` is registered because it's superseded.

```
Transition #1 r0: Started  -> "Transition#1( 'intro'{} -> 'foo'{} )"
Transition #1 r0: <- Rejected "Transition#1( 'intro'{} -> 'foo'{} )", reason: TransitionRejection(type: 2, message: The transition has been superseded by a different transition, detail: 'bar'{"id":"uuid-1234-uuid"})
Transition #2 r0: Ignored  <> "Transition#2( 'intro'{} -> 'intro'{} )"
Transition #3 r0: Started  -> "Transition#3( 'intro'{} -> 'bar'{"id":"uuid-1234-uuid"} )"
Transition #3 r0: <- Success  "Transition#3( 'intro'{} -> 'bar'{"id":"uuid-1234-uuid"} )", final state: bar
```

Note: globally there's a catch all, it's used for auth control when a user does not resolve when loading a state:

```
// state 'intro' is '/'
.config($urlRouterProvider => {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/'); 
})
.run(($transitions, $trace) => {
  $trace.enable('TRANSITION');
  $transitions.onError({}, trans => trans.router.stateService.go('intro'));
}
```

The transition snippet

```
// there is no foo component, it's a straight redirect
.component('bar', {
  template: someTemplate,
  controller: someCtrl
})
.config($stateProvider => {
  let states = [
    {
      name: 'foo',
      url: '/foo',
      redirectTo: { state: 'bar', params: { id: 'uuid-1234-uuid' } }
    },
    {
      name: 'bar',
      url: '/bar/:id',
      component: 'bar'
    }
  ];

  states.forEach(s => $stateProvider.state(s));
})
```

While in this example of `intro -> foo` eventually it ends up in the correct state `bar`, other transitions (when not going from `intro(default)` to `bar`, but from `baz, qux, ..` to `bar`) end up in an endless transition loop.

For example, going from `qux` to `foo`, which should redirect to `bar`, but gets caught in a `qux -> intro` loop: (I don't have earlier error messages of `qux -> foo` because the browser crashes)

```
TransitionRejection(type: 2, message: The transition has been superseded by a different transition, detail: Transition#2704( 'qux'{} -> 'intro'{} ))
```

Does anyone have a solution to the redirect, or can see if I'm using the global catch-all correctly? Catch all is causing the death loop, but that's secondary to the problem of redirect-reject that triggered it in the first place.

Comment: It could be that my usage isn't correct, but not sure why redirect triggers `transition.onError`. A patch is to refine match criteria: `$transition.onError({ to: state => !state.redirectTo }, trans => trans.router.stateService.go('intro'));` rather than an a `.onError({}, ...)`

Answer (score 13):

Transition superseded error occurs when you try to trigger a state change before previous state change event has completed.
A simple way to solve this problem is by calling the state change after a timeout. Which allows current state change to be completed and then triggers the next state change.

```
 $timeout(function(){
   $state.go('statename')
})
```

Note: The timeout here has no defined time, that simply means it will be executed after all current processes are done

Comment: This answer worked for me. +1 (What moron gave it a minus 1?)

Comment: Brill. Ta! Worked a treat. Can't understnad why this was given -1!

Answer (score 0):

If you return a target state from the transition hooks instead of using stateService.go, then this problem should go away as far as my current understanding of ui-router goes.

Comment: return trans.router.stateService.target('stateB');

Comment: though return values are ignored for onError hook so the above solution won't apply in your case.

Comment: "trans" is not a valid provider. Can you give a code example that actually works?

Answer (score 0):

In version 1.0.20
use trans.router.stateService.target('sth') instead of $state.go('sth)

Comment: Can you highlight the difference? To me, both calls look the same